# AngularJS with NodeJS GET request fails - "Access-Control-Allow-Headers is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, http, http-headers

I've been looking around for some similar questions in search of an answer but I can't find it. I have a node.js server with express:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Headers");
  next();
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/assets'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```

And AngularJS working with GET requests to a REST API. They're triggered by keyup events in a searchform. The app.config:

```
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Headers';
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('TokenInterceptor');
});
```

... And the request code itself:

```
$scope.requestMovies = function() {
    $http.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=' + $scope.titleToSearch +
     '&type=movie&r=json')
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.movies = data.Search;
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      alert("No movie found");
    });
  };
```

This worked fine until I added authentication to my project (hence the interceptor), and since then I invariably get an error message
 `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=darkmovie&type=movie&r=json. Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Headers is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.` 

even though I DID authorize the headers both in the front and back end. Same thing happens in Firefox as it does in Chrome. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Forgot to post my TokenInterceptor service:

```
app.service('TokenInterceptor', function($q, $window, $location, AuthenticationService) {
  return {
    request: function (config) {
      config.headers = config.headers || {};
      if ($window.sessionStorage.token) {
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $window.sessionStorage.token;
      }
      return config;
    },

    requestError: function(rejection) {
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    },

    /* Set Authentication.isAuthenticated to true if 200 received */
    response: function (response) {
      if (response !== null && response.status == 200 && $window.sessionStorage.token && !AuthenticationService.isAuthenticated) {
        AuthenticationService.isAuthenticated = true;    
      }
      return response || $q.when(response);
    },

    /* Revoke client authentication if 401 is received */
    responseError: function(rejection) {
      if (rejection !== null && rejection.status === 401 && ($window.sessionStorage.token || AuthenticationService.isAuthenticated)) {
        delete $window.sessionStorage.token;
        AuthenticationService.isAuthenticated = false;
        $location.path("/");
      }

      return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
  };
});
```

Although I still fail to see what's wrong. This was suppose to be a way to check for the authorization token sent from the server everytime an angular view changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was delegating **ALL requests** to an **EXTERNAL** API to the **CLIENT**. I should have figured that this was terrible (and apparently impossible). But since it worked the first time (and I have no idea how or why) I kept my architecture like that. So now basically what I do is:
The client now POSTS the URL parameter to the server:

```
$scope.requestMovies = function() {
    $http.post('/requestMovies', {title: $scope.titleToSearch})
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log(data.Search);
      $scope.movies = data.Search;
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      alert("No movie found");
    });
  };
```

Which handles the GET request for it using a [handy node package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rest-client):

```
var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
var client = new Client();
//(...)

app.post('/requestMovies', function(req, res, next) {

  client.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=' + req.body.title + '&type=movie&r=json', function(data, response){
    console.log('CLIENT RESPONSE DATA :' + data);
    res.send(data);
  });

});
```

And of course, the server has any permission to do any kind of requests. I hope this helps anyone out there.

Answer (score 0):

Change that last one to

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
```

Comment: It didn't make it worse, but also didn't fix the problem

Comment: Try modifying your headers.common to `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*';`

Comment: I also tried that in a previous iteration, and did not work. Interesting fact: I'm noticing that every request is being sent as OPTIONS rather than GET. Unfortunately I can't remember if it's just happening now or if it did before

Comment: Hmm apparently wildcards aren't supported for access-control-allow-headers in some instances. Perhaps try configuring both client and server side to accept the same headers?

Comment: Yes, both do. The strange thing is that this worked before. It's driving me to the brink of insanity...

Comment: Have you tried removing `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common` line altogether? I never found that to be necessary, only the server needed to have the necessary headers.

Comment: Also tried that. It was the initial state of the app, pre-auth. Doing that results in a Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers. error message.

Comment: Did you add Authorization to access-control-allow-headers? e.g. `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Authorization', "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Headers");`

Comment: Yes... as before. I am now trying to make the server do the GET request to the api as a response t the client's GET request. Is that a good architecture?